# Iterate through an Array with a condition

Tags: c#

I have an array of unknown size. The size of the array will determine the color of other controls. The first 10 items in the array will follow a predictable pattern. Seeing that the array size can be any size and me dreaming up new colors past 100 will be exhausting (imagine 500 unique colors!)

How I can loop through the colors past 10?  For instance the array.count is 11. The first 10 is predictable. Lets say 0=red, 1=blue, 2=black, 3=yellow 10= should now be red because it exceeds 10 and starts over.

for instance

```
10 = Red 20 = Red 30=Red 40 = Red
11=blue 21=blue 31=blue 41=blue
12=black 22=black 32=black
13=yellow; 23=yellow; 33=yellow
```

and carry on like this depending on how big the array is (could be a thousand). Though of using something like mod but that fails for me or I could write the longest IF ever.

at the end the code will roughly look like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        color = red
    }
    else if (i == 1)
    {
        color = blue
    }
    //...
```

Comment: In a `for (int i = 0 ...`) loop `(i % 10)` will return 0..9 cyclically, if that's what your looking for?

Comment: What about using mod fails for you? Can you show us what you tried? Using a modulo operation seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: And yet modulo seems exactly what you're going for here. Study the pattern of `Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => colors[i % colors.Length])`.

Comment: 500 unique colors is quite imaginable... it's even very few by today standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mention in the comments, make use of the Modulo operator:

```
void Main()
{
    var controls = Enumerable.Range(1,100).Select(i => new Control()).ToArray(); //create an Control[] with 100 controls.
    var colors = new[] {"Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"}; //create a string[] holding your various color values

    //assign a color to each control
    for (int i=0; i<controls.Length; i++)
    {
        controls[i].Color = colors[i % colors.Length];
    }

    //show the result
    foreach (var control in controls)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(control.Color);
    }
}

class Control 
{
    public string Color{get;set;}
}
```